# Why can't we capture this in a lambda that is the default parameter of a method?

Tags: c++, lambda, this, default-arguments

I'm attempting to capture the `this` pointer within a lambda function that serves as the default parameter for a method.

My goal is to invoke a method of this class from within the lambda, which necessitates capturing the `this` pointer.

However, the following code results in an error:

> error C3639: a lambda that is part of a default argument can only have an init-capture

What is a common solution to overcome this limitation?

```
#include <functional>

class A{
    public:
    void B(std::function<void()> a = [this](){}); //error C3639: a lambda that is part of a default argument can only have an init-capture.
};
```

Comment: this `this` is obsolete https://godbolt.org/z/q57dvPeG5

Comment: If memory serves, arguments (even default ones) are evaluated on the caller side. So what *is* `this` in that case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with the line ...

> ```cpp
> void B(std::function<void()> a = [this](){});
> ```

... is that the lambda expression is default argument to a function parameter.
Function arguments are created at the call site, and there is no `this` that could be captured at that point.
The C++ standard prohibits `this` in default arguments:

> [ *Note*: The keyword `this` may not appear in a default argument of a member function; see [[expr.prim.this]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.this).
> [ *Example*:
>
> ```cpp
> class A {
>   void f(A* p = this) { }           // error
> };
> ```
>
> — end example ]  — end note ]

- [[dcl.fct.default] p8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.default#8)

This is just a note, but it is true for lambdas as well because:

> A *lambda-expression* appearing in a default argument shall not implicitly or explicitly capture any entity.

- [[expr.prim.lambda.capture] p9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda.capture#9)

#### Rationale for why `this` cannot be used in default arguments

A function call is processed as follows:

1. initialize all the function arguments (possibly using default arguments)
2. transfer control to the function (`this` is now available)
3. execute the function body and create the returned object
4. transfer control back to the caller (`this` is no longer available)
5. destroy the function arguments

*Note: the order of steps 4. and 5. is implementation-defined*

You're trying to access `this` in step 1, which is too early, not to mention that lambdas in default arguments can't have captures in general.

#### Solution

Adding a second overload such as

```cpp
void B() { B( [this] {} ); }
```

would fix the problem, but you would end up with two functions instead of one.

Answer (score 7):

You can instead overload the function

```
class A{
    public:
    void B(std::function<void()> a);
    void B(){ B([this](){}); };
};
```

Comment: note that question is actually two, related but slightly different questions, "why not?" (title) and "what to use instead?". This perfectly answers the latter but not the first.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I think it makes sense that you cannot pass lamda with capture list as default argument. it creates dependencies that should not be there.

But you probably can achieve what you want to do with something like this:

```
#include <functional>

class A{
    public:
    void B(std::function<void()> a) {
        if (!a) {
            // do default. You have access to 'this' here.
            return;
        }
        // do non-default with 'a' argument
    }
};
```

Comment: Adding unnecessary branches into code is bad thing for performance.